# How can I deserialise an XML element into an array of elements with both attributes and text in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am having a problem trying to deserialise this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<links>
    <link title="ABC">http://abc.co.uk</link>
    <link title="eBay">http://ebay.co.uk</link>
    <link title="Best Damn Site on the Web">http://stackoverflow.com</link>
</links>
```

Using the code:

```
[XmlRoot("links")]
public class LinksInterface
{
    [XmlElement("link")]
    public List<LinkElement> Links;

    public class LinkElement
    {
        [XmlAttribute("title")]
        public string Title;
        [XmlText] // This bit is the troublesome bit!
        public LinkElement Link;
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to put the text contents of the element into `Links.Link` but the attribute I am trying `[XmlText]` does not provide the behaviour I'd expect and I get the error:

*There was an error reflecting field 'Links'.*.

If anyone could point out the error of my ways, I would be most grateful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps just use `string`:

```
[XmlText]
public string Link {get;set;}
```

At the moment the class is recursive (a tree) - I don't think that is what you intended.

(I also switched to a property, but that isn't the problem - `string` is the biggie; but there are **lots** of reasons to use properties instead of fields, and with auto-properties (C# 3.0) there are few excuses not to)

---

Edit: also, try looking at the inner-most exception; in this case, the message is:

> Cannot serialize member 'Link' of type LinksInterface.LinkElement. XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.

That gives a reasonable indication of where the problem is ;-p

Comment: Also changed to properties instead of fields. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ignore the -1... clicked the down arrow by mistake, won't let me re-up it... Sorry :S

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article [XML Serialization in C#](http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=236).  The author uses a getter/setter to add items to the collection (array in the article) and apply the attribute `[XmlElement("link")]` to the getter/setter.

Cheers.