# Deserialising XML based on attribute values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have some XML that I need to deserialise

```
<element>
  <childElement key="myKey1">a value</childElement>
  <childElement key="myKey2">another value</childElement>
</element>
```

Into a class like

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="element")]
public class Element
{
  public string MyKey1 { get; set; }
  public string MyKey2 { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible for me to annotate MyKey1 and MyKey2 so that if the xml above is deserialised then MyKey1 will be "a value" and MyKey2 will equal "another value"? If not then what is the best approach to deserialising attributes like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML De-serialize into type based on attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482354/xml-de-serialize-into-type-based-on-attribute)

Comment: @PreetaSangha That is a slightly different case. They want to use different elements based on the attributes. I want to use the value in the attribute as the element name

Comment: what about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755178/how-can-i-deserialise-an-xml-element-into-an-array-of-elements-with-both-attribu?rq=1

Comment: @PreetSangha similar, but also slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XmlAttribute` attribute but your xml seems better to fit to a `Dictionary<string,string>`

Using Linq To Xml

```
string xml = @"<element>
    <childElement key=""myKey1"">a value</childElement>
    <childElement key=""myKey2"">another value</childElement>
</element>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var dict = xDoc.Descendants("childElement")
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("key").Value, x => x.Value);

Console.WriteLine(dict["myKey1"]);
```

Comment: That's great thanks, only a little bit more code, but probably more obvious than any complicated attribute based approach.